# Selenium + jmeter script execution

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I am using jmeter OS Process to execute my selenium script. If I ran my python script individually, it will pass. The issue is when I put it in threads of 10 some of them failed. My question is does selenium need to "see" the screen to locate the element? From multiple threads, screens pop up very quickly, I think sometimes the first screen is not fully loaded and the next thread/Screen will pop up and cover the previous screen. I think that is why some of them failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium does not need to "see" the screen to locate elements. That is the basic principle behind headless tests. A browser (headless, visible, or otherwise) creates a representation of the page in memory: a [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). Selenium is then able to interact with that representation using the [WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver).

In all likelihood you need to make generous use of [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/) in order to have your tests run correctly.